# SQL query not providing range for nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to do is get a range of cube numbers within our building. The issue being the the cube number data type is nvarchar. I know its what messing me up but I have no control over the DB also all of our cube numbers are prefaced with a couple of chars such as AA-1 through AA-255 (thus the nvarchar). My question is this why does the below work:

```
Select 
    PCName, 
    CubeNumer
From 
    thisTable
where 
    CubeNumber like 'AA-[1-9]'
```

The above will give me the PCNames for AA-1 through AA-9 but when I do the following:

...

```
where CubeNumber like 'AA-[1-20]'
```

it gives me AA-1 and AA-2. I see the 1 and 2 there, I get its not seeing it as a 20. So is it possible to get that range to work, or any range beside 1-9 to work with that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is a string comparison and therefore will will look for specific strings.  Your pattern of 'AA-[1-20]' is looking for anything that starts with AA- and then numbers 1 through 2, or 0.  The correct way would be to do 'AA-[0-9]*'

If your cubes always start with AA-, you could also do a replace and then cast to convert the cube numbers to actual numbers and then do a BETWEEN query.

```
CAST(REPLACE(CubeNumber,'AA-','') as INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

Comment: I never thought about using a replace thanks for the prompt reply the cast worked.